# Remove Rows Non-Max Count of Non-Unique Column to Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

The title is weird, I know. But I don't know how to express the problem concisely.
Suppose I have a `DataFrame` with two columns like this.

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   1   a
3   3   c
4   3   c
5   4   d
6   1   b
```

Column A and B are one-to-many relations. I want to remove all rows that satisfy this condition: **For every value in column A that has more than one value in column B, if the total count of value in column B is not maximum, the rows will be deleted. But if one value in column A corresponds to only one value in B or the value belongs to the maximum total count, the rows won't be deleted.** Don't worry, the maximum count will be unique.

In the example, the sixth item will be deleted because it's not the maximum of unique value `1` in `A`. The result is this.

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   1   a
3   3   c
4   3   c
5   4   d
```

Is there any efficient solution to this? I have tried these steps:
 1. Filter duplicated values in column A and B using `nunique`
 2. Get all values in A with more than one value in B
 3. Count according to column B with `count_values` and `nlargest`
 4. Inspect the max value to know B's values
 5. Filter rows that satisfy value A(in step 2) and B(in step 4)

I think the steps are too complicated, and I have to do manual inspection. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one, see explanation in comments. If you need any more explanation please let me know in the comments:

```
# count B values per group A and then only keep the row with the highest count
largest_n = df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().rename('size')
largest_n = largest_n.reset_index(level=1).groupby('A').head(1)

# join the row with the highest count back 
df = df.set_index('A').join(largest_n['B'], lsuffix='', rsuffix='_largest')

# then check where B in original dataframe == to B highest count
df = df.query('B == B_largest').reset_index().drop(columns='B_largest')

   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
4  3  c
5  4  d
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you!